# Bad value height div found through jquery. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the script in the loop detects the height of all divs, and then sets the highest value for all to make them div the same in height - specifically, the title. The script reads the height correctly from the first one, but not from the others, so it sets the height value according to the first div. In the chrome debugger at (this), I always see a different height value, but the function still takes the original one.

```js
  $(function() {
            var maxh = 0;
            var maxhnew = 0;
            $('.entry-header').map(function() {
              var testVar = $('#test2').height();
                var idname = 0;
                var idname = $(this).attr("class");
                   var maxhnew = $('.'+ idname ).height(); 
                    if(maxh < $('.'+ idname ).height()) {
                            maxh = $('.'+ idname ).height();
                    }
                                    var maxhnew = 0;
                });

            $('.entry-header').map(function() {
                var idname = $(this).attr("class");
                            $('.'+ idname ).height(maxh);
                    });
                });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="items-row sppb-row row-0 row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-1 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header"id="test1">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-2 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header" id="test2">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title, one row title, one row title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
    </article>
    <!-- end item --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end col-sm-* -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-3 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header" id="test3">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </article>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate dom element height like this. To maintain the div's height according to the highest one, You can do it easily with css clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should work .. Don't use `.attr('class')` In this case it's enough to use `$(this)` to get the height . If you want to pass/save any values you can use `data-` attribute

**So the problem is:** by using `$('.' + idname ).height()` this line of code read as `$('.entry-header').height()` and while you have multiple element with the `.entry-header` class so it returns the height of the first one

```js
$(function() {
  var maxh = 0;
  var maxhnew = 0;
  $('.entry-header').each(function() {
    var testVar = $('#test2').height();
    if(maxh < $(this).height()) {
      maxh = $(this).height();
    }
    maxhnew = 0;
  });
  $('.entry-header').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxh);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="items-row sppb-row row-0 row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-1 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header"id="test1">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-2 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header" id="test2">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title, one row title, one row title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
    </article>
    <!-- end item --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end col-sm-* -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-3 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header" id="test3">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </article>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

<sup>It's OK to use `.map()` But I always used to use `.each()`</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you very much.I don't know why, but I wrote "thanks" on the day of your post and I don't see it here at all.

Comment: Yes I saw it and I replied **"You're totally welcome @Superbobo75 .. Have a great day :)"** But I don't see it either

Answer (score 0):

You're doing some gymnastics with your map functions, and you have some unused variables (like maxhnew).  It's probably much easier to do this with the `each` method, instead of map.  Then the current element in the each is available as `$(this)`.   I think this snippet is what you're looking for:

```js
$(function() {
  var maxh = 0;
  $('.entry-header').each(function() {
    if(maxh < $(this).height()) {
      maxh = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  $('.entry-header').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxh);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="items-row sppb-row row-0 row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-1 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header"id="test1">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-2 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header" id="test2">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title, one row title, one row title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
    </article>
    <!-- end item --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end col-sm-* -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="bt-inner item column-3 item-featured" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
      <div class="entry-image intro-image"> </div>
      <div class="entry-header" id="test3">
        <h2 itemprop="name">one row title 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="autoreadmore">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </article>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```